# JPA 1: JPQL for ORDER BY NULLS LAST

Tags: jpa, toplink

Is there a way to do an ordering in JPQL query like:

```
SELECT v 
FROM Vehicle v 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY v.lastUserUpdate DESC NULLS LAST, v.id DESC;
```

The `NULLS LAST` breaks the query. Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: [This](http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2011/12/problem-withjpa-join-column-null-values-and-orderby/) might be helpful?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've read this already. He's mapping the result to some helper object. I'm looking for a way to retrieve the entity object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a JPQL function to allow this as I believe it is database specific.  JPA 2.0 has a 'SQL' key word that you can use to have "nulls last" passed through.  Something like
  "ORDER BY v.lastUserUpdate DESC SQL('NULLS LAST'), ..."

See 
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.ca/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html for more details on what is available in JPA and eclipselink.  TopLink uses EclipsLink for JPA, so you will have to verify the version you are using and use native TopLink API if it doesn't support it and you can't upgrade.

Comment: Toplink unfortunately doesn't like it.

Comment: It is new to JPA 2.0, while pure TopLink only had a preview JPA 1.0 support.  What version of TopLink are you using?

Comment: EclipseLink also supports NULLS LAST directly, ORDER BY v.lastUserUpdate DESC NULLS LAST should work (as of EclipseLink 2.4)

Comment: @Chris: The one comming with Glassfish 2.1.2 (2.1-b60e-fcs (12/23/2008)).

Comment: JPA2.0 and JPA2.1 do NOT have an "SQL keyword". This is vendor specific, so only use if you don't care about portability.